# Parse beforeSave() cloud code function not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have added a beforeSave() Parse cloud function defined that is not working correctly.

Here is the background:
I have a class called **UserRewards** that has a column called **user** of type *ParseRelation*. It consists of exactly 1 relation which has a single object of type *ParseUser*. I have a new column **pUser** that I would like to set in this function. It looks up the **user** relation, finds the *ParseUser* in it, and sets **pUser** to that user.

Here's the code I have

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("UserRewards", function(request, response) {
    var relation = request.object.relation("user");
    relation.query().find({
            success: function(list) {
                console.log("looked up relation");
                if (list.length > 0) {
                    var pUser = list[0];
                    request.object.set("pUser", pUser);
                    console.log("updated pUser");
                }
            },
                error: function(error) {
                console.error("unable to lookup relation");
            }
    });
    response.success();
```

});

When I update a **UserRewards** row, this function is being called. But it does nothing - no console or error logs whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function runs response.success() before the query completes, thereby canceling it.  Try...

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("UserRewards", function(request, response) {
    var relation = request.object.relation("user");
    relation.query().find({
            success: function(list) {
                console.log("looked up relation");
                if (list.length > 0) {
                    var pUser = list[0];
                    request.object.set("pUser", pUser);
                    console.log("updated pUser");
                }
                response.success();
            },
                error: function(error) {
                console.error("unable to lookup relation");
                response.error(error);
            }
    });
});
```

Or, easier to look at with promises...

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("UserRewards", function(request, response) {
    var relation = request.object.relation("user");
    relation.query().find().then(function(list) {
        console.log("looked up relation");
        if (list.length > 0) {
            var pUser = list[0];
            request.object.set("pUser", pUser);
            console.log("updated pUser");
        }
        response.success();
    }, function(error) {
        console.error("unable to lookup relation");
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

**EDIT** I think I understand the followup question as asking to synch the pointer attribute with the relation attribute, assuming only one of them is set before the save.  This can be done by detecting that the relation is empty.  If it is, do one more asynch step to fetch the pointer...

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("UserRewards", function(request, response) {
    var relation = request.object.relation("user");
    relation.query().find().then(function(list) {
        console.log("looked up relation");
        if (list.length > 0) {
            var pUser = list[0];
            request.object.set("pUser", pUser);
            console.log("updated pUser");
            return Parse.Promise.as();  // we're done, this will pass nothing to the next step
        } else {  // the relation is empty, so the user pointer must be set
            var pointer = request.object.get("pUser");
            return pointer.fetch();    // this will pass the pUser to the next step
        }
    }).then(function(pUser) {
        if (pUser) {
            // must have found an empty relation in the last step.  add the user pointer to it
            request.object.relation.add(pUser);
        }
        response.success();
    }, function(error) {
        console.error("unable to lookup relation");
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

(Note the code is untested).

Comment: Hi danh, thanks for your answer. That did the trick. I have a follow up question. What if I want to check if the relation is set, and then set the pointer if not set. And set the relation if not set but the pointer is set? Feel free to modify your answer above. The promises one is good.

Comment: @amit - gave it my best shot.

Comment: in the second step, i think it needs to cehck for if (pointer).. add(pointer)

Comment: I can't remember if the relation is uninitialized whether you get an undefined query or one that answers empty.  In the second block, the param is the fetched result of the pointer, and that can be set directly into the relation.

Comment: The relation is initialized (if you check for if(relation) it passes) but if you call query() on this empty relation, Parse cloud code crashes, without the error handler being called. I think its a bug in Parse.